# Entity: Job Action: process_membership Failing due to DB error

Tags: civimember, upgrade, status

***General Config:***
Wordpress 5.8
CiviCRM 5.39.1
Cron running ever 5 min successfully
Segregated db from the wp install

***Issue:***
We notice our memberships are not moving from one status to another:  New to Current to Grace to Expired. Rules seem to be properly configured.

Entity: Job Action: process_membership
Summary
Finished execution of Update Membership Statuses with result: Failure, Error message: DB Constraint Violation - membership_type_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for Membership,create API. If so, please raise a bug report.
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message:
Finished execution of Update Membership Statuses with result: Failure, Error message: DB Constraint Violation - membership_type_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for Membership,create API. If so, please raise a bug report.

According to the DB the membership_type_id does not allow nulls.

Kinda lost on this one and not finding an online example here or through the googles.

Answer (score 2):

There was a botched install of CiviVolunteer that did not have all of its tables present.  It could not be installed or uninstalled. I copied over missing tables from an older db. Reran the install and ran the uninstall.  DB errors gone and manually ran the process_membership and all worked as expected.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can mark it as answered using the big green tick.